# Deleting a file after closing

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get my app to delete a pdf file after the Acrobat Reader (with this file) closes.
If I do this:

```
    Process.Start("d:\test.pdf")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("d:\test.pdf")
```

Acrobat gives me an error: "There was an error opening this document. This file cannot be found."

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

***EDIT***

I modified the code a little bit...

```
    Dim MyProc = Process.Start(path)
    MyProc.WaitForExit()
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path)
```

And it deletes the PDF after it is closed, but not if there is another PDF opened...

Comment: Youd be better off using a temp folder and temp file names and just delete them all when the app starts

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for `Process`?  There are things there that should do what you want to do.  In particular, I'd suggest looking at `EnableRaisingEvents`.  (There is also other important information on using the `Process` class properly.)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the event from your process to get the job done.

```
    Dim MyProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("d:\test.pdf")
    AddHandler MyProc.Exited, Sub() My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("d:\test.pdf")
```

Comment: It didn't delete the PDF after closing, so I modified it a little, see original post in the edit section...

Comment: Does this work as you need it to, or do you require further assistance?

Comment: it didn't delete the PDF, but I think I will drop the deletion for now, as I see that I can overwrite the file without any issue...

Answer (score 0):

u can add a timer and set timer to check if acrobart.exe is running :

```
 Public sub Btn1_click

  Process.Start("file path here")

  Timer1.start

  Public sub Timer1_tick

  Dim pr As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("acrobat") 'change acrobat with necessary exe name as i can't remember the exact name of acrobat.exe , it could be acrobat32 or acrobat64 or just acrobat as mentioned
  If pr.Length = 0 Then
  timer1.stop
  My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("d:\test.pdf")
   Else   
  End If
```

This will get the job done!

Comment: Why are you repeatedly trying to look up the process by name instead of retaining the process object that was returned from `Process.Start`?  Hard-coding the name is a very bad idea if this is something that might end up outside of a tightly-controlled environment; I have a personal computer where a different program is the default pdf reader and I don't have Acrobat installed at all.

Comment: Like @Craig said, my PC uses Google Chrome to open PDF's rather than AR.

Comment: have u tried the code yet??as far as i think, this is the only possible way to do it